# Connection error with x509 auth in mongodb Studio 3t

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I am using a licensed version of studio 3t and trying to setup a connection with x509.
Able to connect thru mongo shell with x509 auth with the sslPEMKeyFile & sslCAFile. Getting error in studio 3t with the same files. The pem file is protected with a passphrase.

```
SSL Factory error: error decrypting private key from /Users/test/Documents/Team/Mongodb/3.6.5/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-3.6.5/bin/pem/testapp/testapp.pem: unable to read encrypted data: unable to create InputDecryptor: class javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec (javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec and javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Stacktrace:
|_/ SSL Factory error: error decrypting private key from /Users/test/Documents/Team/Mongodb/3.6.5/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-3.6.5/bin/pem/testapp/testapp.pem: unable to read encrypted data: unable to create InputDecryptor: class javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec (javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec and javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
|____/ Certificate error: error decrypting private key from /Users/test/Documents/Team/Mongodb/3.6.5/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-3.6.5/bin/pem/testapp/testapp.pem: unable to read encrypted data: unable to create InputDecryptor: class javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec (javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec and javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
|_______/ org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: unable to create InputDecryptor: class javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec (javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec and javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
|__________/ org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: unable to create InputDecryptor: class javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec (javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec and javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
|_____________/ java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec (javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec and javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

If I select my client cert is not protected by a passphase, getting the below error as it is protecetd.

```
SSL Factory error: certificate's private key requires password

Stacktrace:
|_/ SSL Factory error: certificate's private key requires password
|____/ Certificate error: certificate's private key requires password
```

If i create a pem file without a passphrase,

```
SSL Factory error: No private keys found in [[], [  [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 4252222979075649915
             IssuerDN: CN=Test Corporate Server CA 1,OU=Certification Authority,O=Test Inc.,C=US
           Start Date: Wed Feb 27 10:27:35 PST 2019
           Final Date: Sun Mar 28 11:27:35 PDT 2021
            SubjectDN: CN=testapp-svc-dev.test.com,OU=management:auth.group.230057,O=Test Inc.,ST=California,C=US
           Public Key: RSA Public Key [15:0d:62:42:ba:bd:b8:0f:75:d1:ff:35:e3:0d:3d:84:96:0b:94:d5]
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001

  Signature Algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
            Signature: a62ef4a4af2b4ee7c55ddc8ea1da9ca70eb4b9a2
                       eab74c856eeb871d98712ac65764893eb6a3f687
                       0629ba4d10768ce343c175f337f8fcb220416eea
                       c17455608b4aec55c250f12c9921a444ada65373
                       4db470db6ba335a88c102461676c859e55ddcec1
                       5bae72c842a236cd46735e209e406a1a6f09659b
                       d632c7c42f7c34dc3d15c2a7430a5caff231560d
                       93a31515ea9aa335360b74103b1eda1193ac48c4
                       d79ceecb4fdfd5ec9797506a537a8d70efac56ba
                       cc6f875b71b92abc46dc468698d3e48031119d85
                       91472b8bc786ade31f75a2b05288e93ef099df71
                       296833c7b47203b8c7a982c3edc77d8ba662af9a
                       1c5967b9972b6b8ff9511834186e71f0
       Extensions: 
                       critical(true) BasicConstraints: isCa(false)
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.35 value = Sequence
    Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[45] 
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[44] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.17 value = Sequence
    Tagged [2] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[35] 
    Tagged [2] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[30] 
    Tagged [2] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[31] 
    Tagged [2] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[31] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.32 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113635.100.5.15.2)
        Sequence
            Sequence
                ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.2)
                Sequence
                    UTF8String(Reliance on this certificate by any party assumes acceptance of any applicable terms and conditions of use and/or certification practice statements.) 
            Sequence
                ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1)
                IA5String(https://certificatemanager.test.com/#help/policies/corporate) 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.37 value = Sequence
    ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
    ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.31 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        Tagged [0]
            Tagged [0]
                Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
                    DER Octet String[43] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.14 value = DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(true) KeyUsage: 0xa0
]]
```

Its not working in any case whereas I am able to connect thru shell with the same pem files. Is this a bug in studio 3t?

> Studio 3t version - 2020.6.0

Comment: What do the pem files contain?

Comment: Certificate and private key. The same pem file works thru mongo shell.

Comment: Was it working in 2020.5?

Comment: Never checked before. This is the first time testing x59 with Studio 3t

Comment: What is the shell command that you use to connect?